# How to make dummy variable in RDD format data read from Hive

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I was thinking to create a dummy variable dataset in Pyspark, and has loaded data from a hive table and stored data in RDD format.

data size is 20000000*11(row * column)

(on cluster) RDD converted hive table into a nested list and I am confused about the way of processing it (different from python).

**Question**：is there any way to maintain the first two variables(**id** and **lable**) and insert a new variable to identiy **label** (as nominal vairable e.g. group_1, group_2, based on conditional assignment) before
getting a dummy variable coding (based on the rest of variables)

I have tried to use key-value method, but it is not working. any thoughts would be appreciated.

**desired result(dummuy coding)** 
the length of dummy encoding (0,1) is determined by unique elements of all vaiables across rows.

`[u'007896797eed11ba73dd', u'18-24', 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

**for example**, the above user did not install *ins_com.meitu.meipaimv* so it would be 0 and if *ins_com.meitu.xxxx* is installed then it is 1

**example data**:

`[[u'007896797eed11ba73dd', u'18-24', u'ins_com.meitu.meipaimv,ins_com.babytree.apps.pregnancy,ins_com.sankuai.meituan,ins_cn.damai,ins_com.google.android.gms,ins_com.taobao.taobao,ins_com.sina.weibo,ins_com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar,ins_com.tencent.qqmusic,ins_com.tencent.mm,ins_com.lemon.faceu,ins_com.zhihu.android,ins_com.Qunar,ins_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,ins_com.airbnb.android,ins_com.lingan.seeyou,ins_com.qicai.translate,ins_com.mt.mtxx.mtxx,ins_vz.com,ins_com.ganji.android,ins_com.google.android.gsf,ins_com.taobao.trip,ins_com.mfw.roadbook,ins_com.tencent.mobileqq', u'act_cn.damai,act_com.taobao.trip,act_com.sankuai.meituan,act_com.google.android.gms,act_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,act_com.tencent.mm,act_com.sina.weibo,act_com.babytree.apps.pregnancy,act_com.taobao.taobao,act_com.meitu.meipaimv,act_com.mfw.roadbook,act_com.zhihu.android,act_com.mt.mtxx.mtxx', u'inst_ct_21_40', u'installed1', u'inst_cate_ct_13_16', u'active_ct_10_20', u'activ_1', u'phone_price_2500_3500', u''], [u'4ac74594b0fe17b532e7f278', u'25-34', u'ins_com.easysay.japanese,ins_com.tencent.mobileqq,ins_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,ins_com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar,ins_com.zhaopin.social,ins_com.taobao.taobao,ins_com.kugou.android,ins_com.sina.weibo,ins_com.tencent.qqlive,ins_cmb.pb,ins_com.android.browser,ins_com.baidu.searchbox,ins_com.sohu.inputmethod.sogou,ins_cn.wps.moffice_eng,ins_com.qiyi.video,ins_com.tencent.mm,ins_com.autonavi.minimap,ins_com.luojilab.player,ins_com.liulishuo.engzo', u'act_com.zhaopin.social,act_com.tencent.mm,act_com.sina.weibo', u'inst_ct_0_20', u'installed12,installed9', u'inst_cate_ct_9_12', u'active_ct_4_5', u'activ_12', u'phone_price_801_1500', u'']]`

Comment: Can you add an example of how you want the data to look after adding the new variable?

Comment: @user3689574, an example has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First finding the full set of elements and fixing the order.

Then maping the data to this set.

```
data_rdd = sc.parallelize([[u'007896797eed11ba73dd', u'18-24', u'ins_com.meitu.meipaimv,ins_com.babytree.apps.pregnancy,ins_com.sankuai.meituan,ins_cn.damai,ins_com.google.android.gms,ins_com.taobao.taobao,ins_com.sina.weibo,ins_com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar,ins_com.tencent.qqmusic,ins_com.tencent.mm,ins_com.lemon.faceu,ins_com.zhihu.android,ins_com.Qunar,ins_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,ins_com.airbnb.android,ins_com.lingan.seeyou,ins_com.qicai.translate,ins_com.mt.mtxx.mtxx,ins_vz.com,ins_com.ganji.android,ins_com.google.android.gsf,ins_com.taobao.trip,ins_com.mfw.roadbook,ins_com.tencent.mobileqq', u'act_cn.damai,act_com.taobao.trip,act_com.sankuai.meituan,act_com.google.android.gms,act_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,act_com.tencent.mm,act_com.sina.weibo,act_com.babytree.apps.pregnancy,act_com.taobao.taobao,act_com.meitu.meipaimv,act_com.mfw.roadbook,act_com.zhihu.android,act_com.mt.mtxx.mtxx', u'inst_ct_21_40', u'installed1', u'inst_cate_ct_13_16', u'active_ct_10_20', u'activ_1', u'phone_price_2500_3500', u''], [u'4ac74594b0fe17b532e7f278', u'25-34', u'ins_com.easysay.japanese,ins_com.tencent.mobileqq,ins_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone,ins_com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar,ins_com.zhaopin.social,ins_com.taobao.taobao,ins_com.kugou.android,ins_com.sina.weibo,ins_com.tencent.qqlive,ins_cmb.pb,ins_com.android.browser,ins_com.baidu.searchbox,ins_com.sohu.inputmethod.sogou,ins_cn.wps.moffice_eng,ins_com.qiyi.video,ins_com.tencent.mm,ins_com.autonavi.minimap,ins_com.luojilab.player,ins_com.liulishuo.engzo', u'act_com.zhaopin.social,act_com.tencent.mm,act_com.sina.weibo', u'inst_ct_0_20', u'installed12,installed9', u'inst_cate_ct_9_12', u'active_ct_4_5', u'activ_12', u'phone_price_801_1500', u'']])

split_data_rdd = data_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], set(x[2].split(","))))

elements_set = sorted(split_data_rdd\
                      .map(lambda x: x[2]).reduce(lambda x,y: x | y))

print elements_set

split_data_rdd_dummy_encoding = split_data_rdd\
     .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], [1 if y in x[2] else 0 for y in elements_set]))

print split_data_rdd_dummy_encoding.collect()
```

Result:

```
[u'ins_cmb.pb', u'ins_cn.damai', u'ins_cn.wps.moffice_eng', u'ins_com.Qunar', u'ins_com.airbnb.android', u'ins_com.android.browser', u'ins_com.autonavi.minimap', u'ins_com.babytree.apps.pregnancy', u'ins_com.baidu.searchbox', u'ins_com.easysay.japanese', u'ins_com.eg.android.AlipayGphone', u'ins_com.ganji.android', u'ins_com.google.android.gms', u'ins_com.google.android.gsf', u'ins_com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar', u'ins_com.kugou.android', u'ins_com.lemon.faceu', u'ins_com.lingan.seeyou', u'ins_com.liulishuo.engzo', u'ins_com.luojilab.player', u'ins_com.meitu.meipaimv', u'ins_com.mfw.roadbook', u'ins_com.mt.mtxx.mtxx', u'ins_com.qicai.translate', u'ins_com.qiyi.video', u'ins_com.sankuai.meituan', u'ins_com.sina.weibo', u'ins_com.sohu.inputmethod.sogou', u'ins_com.taobao.taobao', u'ins_com.taobao.trip', u'ins_com.tencent.mm', u'ins_com.tencent.mobileqq', u'ins_com.tencent.qqlive', u'ins_com.tencent.qqmusic', u'ins_com.zhaopin.social', u'ins_com.zhihu.android', u'ins_vz.com']

[(u'007896797eed11ba73dd', u'18-24', [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]), (u'4ac74594b0fe17b532e7f278', u'25-34', [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: If elements_set is to big to collect, let me know. This can also be done with a join.

Comment: thanks to your answer. It works quit efficiently! I actually use `join` to merge x[3], x[4]... to be x[2] (to have more elements in split_data_rdd and elements_set ).